# How to get current_page_url to say active in jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2 and I'm trying to get my nav to say whether or not it is active. I've managed to do it so far but when I first land on my page the home link isn't set to active so what I'm trying to do is that if my current page is equal to the landing page then the home link must be active and if not then the home page link must not have the class active.

My js

```
var current_page_URL = location.href;
console.log(current_page_URL);
if(current_page_URL == '/'){
    console.log("yes");
}else{
    console.log("no");
}
```

I hope I made sense

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Your question makes sense, but JS code is quite confusing

Comment: what I'm trying to do is that if my url says `http://localhost/site/public/` then the console will have to say yes but if my url says `http://localhost/site/public/3` the console will have to say no. But at the moment it's saying no when the url is `http://localhost/site/public/

Comment: It doesn't. For both of URL, result is `no`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var current_page_URL = location.href;
console.log(current_page_URL);
var home_page_URL = http://localhost/site/public/;
if(current_page_URL == home_page_URL){
    console.log("yes");
}else{
    console.log("no");
}
```

You want something like this?

Comment: yes it's something like that. But is there a way to do it where I don't have to add the url?

Comment: you must be knowing some part of the url? something like home url will be ending with public/ ???

Comment: @Nix : you must be knowing some part of the url? something like home url will be ending with public/ ??? –

Comment: It's probably better then to have the url there.

Comment: @Nix I didn't get you

Comment: I think I will keep the url there by the `var home_page_url` and thank you so much for helping. By doing it like this I was able to do what I needed. Thank you so much.